# RabbitMQ Request-Response pattern - consumer stops listening to queue after processing first message

Tags: rabbitmq, queue

I'm trying to implement RabbitMQ Request-Response pattern.

My goal is that there would be always one consumer that listens to a queue and replies to messages.

So I've set the server up by:

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

channel.BasicConsume(queue: 'listensToThisQueue',
   noAck: true,
   consumer: consumer);

consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{ 
   // Replying to client
   channel.BasicPublish(exchange: '',
            routingKey: routingKey,
            basicProperties: props,
            body: message);
   // Basic ack
   channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: incomingDeliveryTag,
            multiple: false);
}
```

Everything actually works fine:

1. Client sends first message
2. Server receive and reply
3. Client gets the message

The only problem is that after finshing `Received` method (After executing `BasicAck`) - Consumer stops listening to `listenToQueue` (I actually see 0 consumers on this queue in the UI management).

Why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are subscribing to the queue with `noAck` set to `True`. In this case, the consumer crashed after the first message was delivered (which is why you see 0 consumers). So you have to subscribe to the queue with `noAck` set to `False`.

Comment: So actually I can eliminate "BasicAck" and it would work